# Plotting multiple scattter plots in the same graph instead of Facet Grids

Tags: python, seaborn

Currently I have a few plots using Facet Grids in seaborn. I have the following code:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(masterdata1,col = "courseName")
g=g.map(plt.scatter, "SubjectwisePercentage", "SemesterPercentage")
```

The above code plots subjectwisepercentage vs semesterpercentage, for different courses across a semester. How can I plot the different scatter plots in a single plot, instead of multiple plots across the facet grid? In the single plot, the plotted points for each course should be a different color.

There are links online that specify how to plot different datasets in a single plot. However I need to use the same dataset. Therefore I need to specify `col="courseName"`, or something equivalent, to plot course wise data in a single plot. I am not sure of how to accomplish this. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using seaborn's [scatter plot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html#seaborn.scatterplot) features. It allows to define, `x`, `y`, `hue` and `style`, and even `size`. Which gives up to a 5D view of your data. Sometimes, people like to make `hue` and `style` based on the same variables for better-looking graphs.

[image]
[image]

Sample code (not pretty much mine, since the seaborn documentation pretty much explains everything).

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


sns.set(style="ticks", color_codes=True)
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
# g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, col="sex", hue="time", palette="Set1",
#                   hue_order=["Dinner", "Lunch"])
# g= (g.map(plt.scatter, "total_bill", "tip")).add_legend()

# sns.scatterplot(data=tips, x="total_bill", y="tip", hue='time', style='sex')
sns.scatterplot(data=tips, x="total_bill", y="tip", hue='time', style='sex', size='size')
plt.show()
```

The matplotlib [scatter plot](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) can also be helpful. Since you can plot several data on the same plot with different markers/colors/sizes.
See [this](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_masked.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-scatter-masked-py) example.

[image]